How to link a virtual FTS table to another table in SQLite and enforce referential integrity?
I've been reading up on the full text search documentation in SQLite and it all makes sense, except there appears to be no accommodation made for actually being able to link FTS rows with rows in other tables.  I'm guessing I don't want to put all my entity's columns into my FTS table because I can't specify data types (or STRICT) for it, and I don't need all the data to be indexed for a FTS.  So I wanted to use a FK relationship to do a 1:1 link from my main entity table to its FTS table, like so:
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE usersFTS USING fts4(
    keywords,
    nicknames
);

-- Create the users table with an explicit foreign key reference to usersFTS
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    usersFTS_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (usersFTS_id) REFERENCES usersFTS (rowid)
);

-- ... then:

-- Insert into usersFTS and capture the generated rowid for Alice's meta
INSERT INTO usersFTS (keywords, nicknames) VALUES ('software developer linux open-source', 'Ally Alice');

-- Capture the generated rowid for Alice
SELECT last_insert_rowid();  -- Assume it returns 1

-- Insert into users using the captured rowid
INSERT INTO users (name, email, usersFTS_id) VALUES ('Alice', 'alice@example.com', 1);

-- ... so that:

SELECT usr.id, usr.name, usr.email, fts.keywords, fts.nicknames
FROM usersFTS fts
INNER JOIN users usr ON usr.usersFTS_id = fts.rowid
WHERE fts.keywords MATCH '"software developer"';

But this fails at the INSERT statement:

SQL logic error: foreign key mismatch - "users" referencing "usersFTS"

It seems a virtual table can't have its rowid referenced in a normal FK relationship.  So, how can I link a row in my full text search table to a row in another table holding more data on that entity?  Is there any way I can do it in SQLite which maintains referential integrity?

Since FTS table is a virtual one - you cannot create a FK to it. But you can add any additional field to it and build a pseudo FK from it:
create table users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE usersFTS USING fts4(
    id INTEGER,
    keywords,
    nicknames
);

INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ('Alice', 'alice@example.com');

INSERT INTO usersFTS (id, keywords, nicknames)
   VALUES ((select id from users where name='Alice'),
          'software developer linux open-source', 'Ally Alice');

SELECT usr.id, usr.name, usr.email, fts.keywords, fts.nicknames
FROM usersFTS fts
INNER JOIN users usr ON usr.id = fts.id
WHERE fts.keywords MATCH '"software developer"';

Please note, you can not create a real FK to or from virtual table. You can add foreign key constraint but it would be ignored and not be enforced with pragma foreing_keys=on;. Virtual table does not have that capability currently. But you would still have a field to tie to other table.

Even better, would be to have virtual table virtual: keep the texts in a real table, but reference it from the virtual one. There is a special chapter in documentation with a clear example: 6.2.2. External Content FTS4 Tables
